# Best approach for a ipad/iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard

I am going to create an App for both iPhone(4, 4S, 5) and iPad (2, 3, Mini)
What, in your opinion, is the best approach?
1) Having 2 storyboards, 1 for iPhone and 1 for iPad?
2) A single storyboard with duplicate views for each device (1 view for iPhone and 1 for iPad)
3) A single storyboard with a single view but self-adapting according to device?

If I use 2 storyboards, how can I choose which one to launch at startup?

Thank you!

Comment: Best approach is to not use story boards at all

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest route to go would be to use two different storyboards, 1 for iPad and 1 for iPhone. You set the default start up screen in the AppDelegate `viewDidLoad withOptions` method. and in there check to see what device you are running on by

```
NSString *iphone = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"];

if ([iphone isEqualTo:@"iPhone"])
{
//load correct soryboard
}
else
{
//load other storyboard
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also just make you app to be a universal app. Following this [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_ipad___universal_apps) or [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad) might get you where you want to go, but it depends on what type of app you are trying to make.

If this won't work for you, you could use the answer provided by @heinst and use 2 storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the screen height detection concept like so:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
        /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/
    } else {
        /*Do iPhone Classic stuff here.*/
    }
} else {
    /*Do iPad stuff here.*/
}
```